# How to make text go next line in css even if it is not overflow?

Tags: html, css

I'm a newbie in html and css. I'm trying to make text go next line even if the text is not overflowed in css.
Now it gives from the page like,

[image]

However, I want to be like such as

```
Temperature : 13 Celsius
CO2: 345 ppm
Humidity: 13%
```

How can I do such a thing? I tried to find in google but couldn't find any solutions that I want.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**
I actually used tooltip function like below

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});
```

and then the text that I showed above is in `div title`

```
<div id="my id" class="draggable js-drag" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" 
style="display: block; position: absolute; left: 894px; top: 413px;" 
data-x="894" data-y="413" 
data-original-title="Temperature : 13.0 °C CO2 : 345 ppm Humidity : 13.0 %"></div>
```

Comment: Use `<p>` tag for each line

Comment: @CarlJan Thanks for the answer and commenting. I actually used tooltip function(?), and those text is in `div title`. I want it to make those text go next line from that. How can I do that..?

Comment: Can you add the html?

Comment: @CarlJan wait let me edit my question

Comment: What do you mean by "`div title`"? Can you also show that?

Comment: Is is not possible to put it inside the tag?

Comment: If you can not alter the markup of that string, then you would need to use JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use multiple `div`.

The `div` is a `display: block` by default and would occupy the entire space in the line, forcing the other `div` onto the next line.

Refer code:

```html
<div>
  <div>Temperature : 13 Celsius</div>
  <div>CO2: 345 ppm</div>
  <div>Humidity: 13%</div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

To apply a line break in `data-original-title` you need to add `data-html="true"` in your markup. Either you can manually add it in your markup or using `jquery`. And then you can add `<br/>` in your code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip().attr("data-html", "true");
});

<div id="my id" class="draggable js-drag" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-html="true"
style="display: block; position: absolute; left: 894px; top: 413px;" 
data-x="894" data-y="413" 
data-original-title="Temperature : 13.0 °C <br/> CO2 : 345 ppm <br/> Humidity : 13.0 %"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for edited answer.. :'( but doesn't work it doesn't read <br> stuff, It shows like <br> as string :'(

Comment: I think I just have to change the width size of tooltip to be longer.. :'(

Comment: Did you add `data-html="true"` in your html?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle or demo where we can see the code working?

Comment: Oh man I'm sorry, I didn't see that data-html tag in the div...... I set it true and it works now!!!! :) Thank you so much for helping me out!

Answer (score 1):

Simply add `<br/>` to your text to indicate *line break*

```
Temperature : 13 Celsius<br/>
CO2: 345 ppm<br/>
Humidity: 13%<br/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I edited my question and can you read more my question?

Comment: @paulc1111 What plugin do you use? Can you provide SO Snippet instead of plain code?

Answer (score 0):

Would this do?

```
<p>Temperature : 13 Celsius</p>
<p>CO2: 345 ppm</p>
<p>Humidity: 13%</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the `DIV` solution, `P` tag would give a default margin value which is not required for a simple line break.

```
<div>Temperature : 13 Celsius</div>
<div>CO2: 345 ppm</div>
<div>Humidity: 13%</div>
```

You could then set the line-height using

CSS:

```
div{
   line-height:14px; /* for example */
}
```